# Asynchronous call AngularJS not working with Canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, asynchronous

I am trying to add a banner `addBanner()` after a Canvas HTML has been filled with the image source `fillCanvas()`. However, with my current setup, the defferred does not fire when I want it.

What happens now is that within addBanner it thinks that the canvas size is 150x300. However, the image is far bigger 800xZ after fillCanvas() has been called. After everything has been loaded, the canvas loads with the complete image (800xZ) big so the banner is placed in the wrong place.

So how to call first filLCanvas() and when its done, call addBanner()?

Thank you.

**main** - assuming $q is injected in the controller

```
fillCanvas("empty").then(function(canvasOpt) {
          window.alert(canvasOpt.cw) // shows 300, but it should be far larger
          addBanner(canvasOpt);
      },
      function(err) {
          window.alert(err)
      });
```

**fillCanvas()**

```
function fillCanvas() {

    // $q
    var deferred = $q.defer()

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src = "img/struddle.jpg"


    // *****************
    // resize image to 800xZ or Zx800
    // *****************
    var imgOrigWidth = img.width;
    var imgOrigHeight = img.height;


    var resizeRatio = 1;
    if (imgOrigHeight >= imgOrigWidth) {
      resizeRatio = 800/imgOrigHeight;
    } else {
      resizeRatio = 800/imgOrigWidth;
    }


    function start() {        


      canvas.width = img.width*resizeRatio;
      canvas.height = img.height*resizeRatio + 100;

      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width*resizeRatio, img.height*resizeRatio);

      var cw=canvas.width;
      var ch=canvas.height-100;


      }



      var canvasOpt = {
      ch: canvas.height,
      cw: canvas.width
      }

    // $q
    deferred.resolve(canvasOpt);

    // HERE I WANT IT TO SHOW THE SIZE OF THE RESIZED IMAGE, BUT IT SHOWS 150x300 (default value)
    window.alert("start: " + canvasOpt.cw + "x" + canvasOpt.ch)


    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**addBanner(canvasOpt)**

```
function addBanner(canvasOpt) {

  var element = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (!element || !element.getContext) {
  return;
  }

  var context = element.getContext('2d');
  if (!context || !context.drawImage) {
   return;
  }


  // THIS SHOULD BE THE SIZE OF THE RESIZED IMAGE
  var cw = canvasOpt.cw;
  var ch = canvasOpt.ch;

  window.alert("addBanner: " + ch + "x" + cw)      

  context.fillStyle   = '#0066FF'; // set canvas background color
  context.fillRect  (0, ch-100, cw, 100);  // now fill the canvas 

  context.fillStyle    = '#FFFFFF';  // set text color
  context.font         = '16px Verdana';  // set text font
  context.textBaseline = 'top';  // set text position 
  context.fillText  ('Scan the QR code', ch-100, cw);  // set the text with my blogs URL


  // create and draw the google generated qr-code image  
  var google_img = new Image();
  google_img.addEventListener('load', function () {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, ch-100, 50, 50);
  },false);

  var chlStr = "Hello Fabrice"
  google_img.src = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=" + chlStr + "&choe=UTF-8";


} // addBanner()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the "deferred.resolve(canvasOpt)" to the start function in the fillcanvas method, also the image calculation part to the start method.

```
function start() {

            // *****************
            // resize image to 800xZ or Zx800
            // *****************
            var imgOrigWidth = img.width;
            var imgOrigHeight = img.height;


            var resizeRatio = 1;
            if (imgOrigHeight >= imgOrigWidth) {
                resizeRatio = 800 / imgOrigHeight;
            } else {
                resizeRatio = 800 / imgOrigWidth;
            }


            canvas.width = img.width * resizeRatio;
            canvas.height = img.height * resizeRatio + 100;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width * resizeRatio, img.height * resizeRatio);

            var cw = canvas.width;
            var ch = canvas.height - 100;

            var canvasOpt = {
                ch: canvas.height,
                cw: canvas.width
            }

            // $q
            deferred.resolve(canvasOpt);

            // HERE I WANT IT TO SHOW THE SIZE OF THE RESIZED IMAGE, BUT IT SHOWS 150x300 (default value)
            window.alert("start: " + canvasOpt.cw + "x" + canvasOpt.ch)

        }
```

refer the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tedvt37c/1/

Comment: Thanks. That works for calling the function addBanner() After fillCanvas(). However, it does not take into account the new canvas dimensions canvasOpt, basically it initializes again addBanner with 150x300. Any thoughts?